# Initialize global variables with incrementing value

Tags: c++, enums, global-variables

In one of my C++03 components, I am moving from enum to global const int. `enum{ RED=0, GREEN, BLUE };` is changed to `const unsigned int RED = 0, GREEN = 1, BLUE = 2;`

The problem is the for global const variables, you should initialize each value explicitly. e.x. Having enum with 100 value, keeping values in sequence is pretty hard. Imagine you want to remove a value from the middle of this enum, it is a big mess (i.e change the value of all enum values after removed enum)!

I created this work-around, but don't know if the result is guaranteed on different compilers and targets or not.

```
#define CREATE_GLOBAL_COUNT(name, val) static unsigned int g_counter_##name = val
#define INC_GLOBAL_COUNT(name) g_counter_##name ++

CREATE_GLOBAL_COUNT(color, 0);

const int RED = INC_GLOBAL_COUNT(color), 
GREEN = INC_GLOBAL_COUNT(color), 
BLUE = INC_GLOBAL_COUNT(color);
```

**EDIT:** The main motive is to reduce the dependency between header files. Components needs to use an enum should include the enum_definition.h file. In the new solution, they just need to extern the global variables and use it.

Comment: The problems you cite apply to enums as well. Having an explicit *==++color* doesn't add to those problems. Macros are not required in this case, and are best avoided when possible.

Comment: It sounds like you want to keep the enumeration as it is. Why are you changing it?

Comment: @BalogPal the question is "Is this solution standard?"

Answer (score 3):

You should have not change the good-working way to a much worse one.

What was your problem with the enum really? Even Scott Meyers agreed that the "enum hack" is fair game and enumerators approximate named literals way better than const ints. *What btw is also a hack with the implicit static).

Answer (score 1):

Seems simple. What am I missing?

```
const int RED = 0;
const int GREEN = RED + 1;
const int BLUE = GREEN + 1;
```

Now if you decide to remove `GREEN`, the definition of `BLUE` will not compile until you change it to use `RED` instead of `GREEN. All the values after that will be okay; they'll shift down by 1.